# What word best describes a small store that sells only glasses (spectacles)?

Tags: word-choice, signage, terminology

What word would or combination of words would best describe a small store, in which only glasses (spectacles) are sold?

Here are some of my guesses, but I think they are all wrong:

1. Eye ware
2. Glass Shop
3. Glasses Shop
4. Glass Store
5. Glasses Store
6. Optics Store
7. (What's your option?)

I need it for two cases: one is for a sign on that store, the other one is for this sentence:

"Two years earlier she had worked in a (small) ***_*__*_*__**."

It is very possible that there are different words (or combination of words) for these two different cases.

Please, remember that only glasses are being sold in that store/shop.

Comment: Opticians store or simply optician's?

Comment: Is this for a sign or for that sentence? Or it would be good in either case?

Comment: @RegDwight - that's maybe an answer rather than a comment. It's certainly what a store like that would be called in the uk.

Comment: @glenatron: feel free to take it as your answer. I've never been to the UK — [it's a hassle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area) —, so I was just guessing. For instance, I have no idea whether the apostrophe belongs there or not.

Comment: What locale does the OP have in mind?  It seems like the UK seems to be in agreement about `Optician's` but in the US, I'm not sure I've heard that term in this sort of context.

Comment: I would be glad to know precisely how they name it in either locale. As far as I can see, the UK usage is already quite clear (Optician's), but the US usage is still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about "Optician's?"

Comment: I guess it works for a sign, but would this really fit in that sentence: "Two years earlier she had worked in a small optician's"?

Comment: Thanks, Rhodri, but that would work only in the UK, right? I mean, in the USA they wouldn't say this way, right?

Comment: We use the word Optician in Canada too.  Don't know about the US.

Comment: yes, they have opticians in the US.

Comment: In the US, an *optician* is a person. The actual store is not usually called an *optician's*, just like a barber shop is not usually called a *barber's*, and a bakery not usually called a *baker's*.

Answer (score 5):

I would not suggest the use of "glass" or "glasses"; it would not be specific enough to identify the store as somewhere eyeglasses are sold. There are stores that sell collector's edition glasses (as in those that you drink from), and so there could be some confusion involved.

I would also not suggest "optics" as there are other types of optics out there as well - lenses and such for cameras, for example.

"Opticians" (with or without the apostrophe) would imply that the store also provides eye exams, at least to me. If that is the case - that there is an optometrist on site - then this would be a good choice, regardless of whether it is in the UK or here in the US.

I think the K.I.S.S. approach would be best - "eyeglass store". This it to the point and does not leave room for doubt as to what is sold there. It isn't fancy or elegant, but it is about as accurate as you can get.

Comment: Another suggestion would be "eyewear shop". Although Firefox thinks *eyewear* is misspelled. Eh.

Comment: @Martha : I like "eyewear" as well. Perhaps "eyeglass" might only imply prescription lenses; "eyewear" would also include sunglasses and such.

Comment: I thought only ophthalmologists and optometrists could do exams; opticians just make & fit the glasses prescribed by one of the others. At least, in the USA.

Comment: "Eyeglass" to me means telescope before spectacles.

Comment: @Peter : simply out of curiosity, can you elaborate why? I would not normally equate the two, so I am wondering why that correlation makes more sense to you (perhaps it is something I don't normally consider).

Comment: @Will, I'm not sure why I make that association. I speak en-gb, but I don't want to be hasty to suggest that it's a transatlantic difference. Maybe I just read too many nautical adventure stories when I was a teenager. (FWIW the fact that it's singular is definitely relevant).

Comment: @Peter, I can see why it being singular would make a difference. No worries; like I said, I was just curious if there was something specific that you thought of that I had not. Always looking for unique insights into things :)

Answer (score 4):

In the U.S., you should call it an "optical shop" (1.27 million google hits), which I believe is the most common term in American English for it. "Optical store" only gets 1/5 of the hits, although as nohat points out, this is what both LensCrafters and J.C. Penney call their optical shops. I *think* they're trying to make their locations sound a little fancier.

In Britain, as many people have pointed out, it's an "optician's".

Comment: And I don't know why it's "optical shop" and not "optical store", but compare barbershop, coffee shop and bake shop with liquor store and corner store. Some things are shops, some are stores, and some (toy shop; toy store) can be either.

Comment: It's always been a big trouble for me choosing between *store* and *shop*

Comment: And counting Google hits, it appears that an upscale optical shop is an *eyewear boutique*.

Comment: It's "optician" (or "optician's") in the US as well.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, both [LensCrafters](http://www.luxottica.it/en/careers/global_recruiting/global_recruiting_retail/lenscrafters/index.html) and [JC Penney Optical](http://www.jcpenneyoptical.com/storelocator.html) call their retail locations "optical stores".

Comment: That's a good point, but I was more on how common native American English speakers would refer to such outlets among themselves.

Answer (score -1):

Dispensary or optical dispensary.

Comment: Please give a rationale for your answer.